# Auto add primary key in Access form

Tags: ms-access

I want my form to function such that It will have all fields for data but none for Primary key, and when I save the data, It will auto add a primary key to it and add the record to database. But when I try this I get following error:
"You must enter a value in Students.Student_ID field"???

Comment: To do that the column `Student_ID` must be an `AutoNumber` column

Comment: Setting it to AutoNumber doesnot follow the suit of previous Numbers. I am trying to get it to generate the next number in the series.

Comment: If it is not an auto-increment field, or a random generation, you will have to do this by yourself by writing code. Access cannot know what the next value will be unless you tell it.